# NSTimer and CountDown

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to insert in my App a Timer, but I don't know how and in which way I can do this. The timer will be start at 60 seconds and end at 0 seconds, how can do it?

Comment: Start by reading [NSTimer's class reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Comment: Is there anything you have tried to accomplish this? Anything you have researched to accomplish your goal? It would help you on your way for future questions by showing you tried programming something that failed.

Answer (score 3):

Start by noting the date at which the countdown started.

Set up a [repeating NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a) for display purposes, with the interval set to the smallest unit you show the user (e.g., if you're counting down minutes, set it to 1 minute = 60 seconds; if you're counting down seconds, set it to 1 second).

(“Timer” in the Cocoa sense does not refer to a countdown. An NSTimer won't count up or down to a limit set up in advance; it either fires once, or fires periodically at a fixed interval until you stop it.)

Every time the timer fires, get the current date and find out [how long it's been](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceDate%3a) since you started the countdown. Subtract this interval from the desired countdown length.

If the result of the subtraction is positive, the countdown proceeds; update your display with the time remaining. If the result is zero or negative, the countdown time has run out; invalidate the timer and update your display to show zero time remaining.

This approach sets you up to handle a few different cases:

- If this is an iOS app, you can cancel the timer when your app goes into the background or will terminate, then re-create it when the app comes to the foreground again. Since your display is based off the time since the countdown started, rather than just periodically decrementing a counter, it will be correct even if more than 1 interval passes while your app is not active, and even if the countdown expires during that time. Speaking of which…
- On both Mac and iOS, you can schedule a local notification at the countdown expiration time. I think your app doesn't even have to be running anymore, then (but I haven't tested that).
- You can easily change your display to show time elapsed rather than time remaining.
- You can update the display more or less often at will (e.g., to show tenths of a second draining away, or adapt the displayed units to the amount of time remaining).